# How to Create an Excel Add-In Ribbon Button to be available to any workbook I open

Tags: vba, visual-studio, excel, ribbon

I have a code that works perfectly well for me when I assign the code to a button in my excel workbook.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SAVEASPDF()

    'SAVEASPDF Macro

    Dim docname As String
        docname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        docname = Replace(docname, ".xlsm", ".pdf")

        ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                           Filename:= ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & docname, _
                                           Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                           IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                           IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                           OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

However, I would like to create a button (lets call it "SAVE Workbook to PDF") to add to the **Add-In Ribbon** that calls up this code every time I open excel. I am familiar with Visual Studio 2017 so any help would be grateful.

Comment: You need to create and Excel add-in (.xlam) with a single button and your procedure in a standard module. Then you can load the add-in and it will be available in all workbooks. Plenty of examples on the internet on how to do that.

Comment: Hi there. i am a little confused. i created a new excel workbook, i then went to VBA and created a new module with this above code, then closed it, saved the workbook as an .xlam file and then proceeded to open another workbook, managed my excel addins in the options menu  by adding my new addin after pressing go, then i customized the ribbon by adding the addin  to my "home" tab.

Comment: it still does not work. it gives me an error which i have to debug :( - thanks so much for the help

Comment: First create the workbook with the button and all, test it and once everything's in order save it as .xlam and load it. Don't forget to change the VBA Project name to something meaningful. In addition I believe you need to change `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: Hi Kostas. Ive tried it and unfortunately it does not work. perhaps you can assist me in trying to do the same on your side and telling me if it works or not?